# Why CURL return some symbols instead of image?

Tags: php, curl

I use curl parameters:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

�PNG  IHDRx�zB�d,IIDATx���Ϗ��}؋f�����  ���>Y�\f�AӀ/��?�+(���w�����&�ml_4_,`<���o��45�� μc�����}����,;�a��H��*��*��$�U��k������w}�ú��;�μ3��;�μ3��;�μ:W{ݭʍfޯ,�r��y�7�̫ʛ�����K͋�^��e���A��R����y߈x�Fys����=����xy���`2�[�0��r�y ލI}����V����c���bE

And take that result. Why I can't see image?
I need save to file the image

Comment: Congratulations. That's a PNG file, and it's binary data so it will look like garbage as a string. Save it and open it in an image viewer.

Comment: Try opening an existing PNG file in a text editor, and you will see the same.

Comment: Really. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the body directly to a file:

```
$fp = fopen('image.png', 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is an image, but you’re in a text-only command line. Save the contents to a file, and you’ll have an image file.